# Setting objective in python with multiple variables

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I'm trying to use `gurobi` to solve an assignment optimization problem.

I have a **4x4** array to store costs, and I'm trying to multiply it with decision variables stored as a **4x4** array.

I have tried the followings:

```
model.setObjective(quicksum(cost[i,j] * x[i][j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

It returns **key error: 0**

Also,

```
model.setObjective(quicksum(cost[i,j] * x[i,j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

It returns **Variable not in model**

This is my cost array:

```
cost = np.array([[48.3, 5000, 66.0, 55.4], 
                 [50.2, 53.2, 58.9, 56.2], 
                 [47.5, 49.8, 5000, 53.0], 
                 [48.1, 51.8, 64.4, 54.7]])
```

And I set up my variables like this:

```
x = model.addVars(4, 4, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

Ideally, I'd like the code to return which variables I should use to assign appropriate binary variables. i.e. x[0,0] = 1; x[2,3] = 0

Answer (score 1):

The following (your second attempt) works with the latest Gurobi release if the model is contained in a variable named `model` and you added the variables `x` to that same model:

```
model.setObjective(quicksum(cost[i,j] * x[i,j] for i in range(4) for j in range(4)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

but you should use `range(4)` instead of `range(3)` if you want to sum up all of them. Maybe you have multiple models and tried to add the objective to the wrong one?

Comment: thank you! you were right, i had to set it to 4 and indeed there was carelessness from me